# Error in exporting .pod with PVRGeoPOD

Tags: cycles-render-engine, export

I'm using [PVRGeoPOD](https://community.imgtec.com/developers/powervr/tools/pvrgeopod/) trying to export a model with simple rotating animation, however, I kept getting this error message. Wonder if anyone came across this and could give me a hand. Thanks a lot.
Blender file attached to the post.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I would recommend asking on the author's site. Typically when addons don't work, we can't help much.

Comment: Did you get an answer for this ? I'm facing the same issue. I tried to export a simple cube and there was no problem. I had this problem when I was exporting my scene.

Comment: Okay, I figured out something that worked for me but I haven't found the root cause of the problem. I wrote a script to extract vertices and faces data. Then I re-created the mesh using this data of vertices and faces using from_pydata feature in a new blend file. I then triangulated the whole mesh. The export worked now. I went back and tried triangulating my old mesh in the old blend file but that did not work. Only the new triangulated mesh in the fresh blend file worked.

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with cycles engine or blender internal engine. I was working on Blender Internal, and I came across the same problem

Comment: Hey, I asked on Imgtec and eventually got an answer :D Check this link out: https://community.imgtec.com/forums/topic/blender-pvrgeopod-plugin-wont-export/

Answer (score 1):

According to Imgtec, the problem is not all meshes are triangulated. [This python script](https://community.imgtec.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2017/12/PVRGeoPODScript.zip) fixes that.

Full discussion [here](https://community.imgtec.com/forums/topic/blender-pvrgeopod-plugin-wont-export/).